# How can I get a list of my bash aliases in perl?

Tags: perl

I know I can do

```
alias
```

in bash to get a list of my aliases.

I would like to do this in perl:

```
qx(alias)
```

and get the output of the above command to process.

However that isn't working (it works ok with - say `ls`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each bash process has its own list of aliases.

If you want the aliases of a freshly started interactive bash process,<sup>[1]</sup> you could execute

```bash
bash -i -c alias
```

---

To execute the command, you could use

```perl
my $output = qx{bash -i -c alias};
die( "Couldn't execute child: $!\n"               ) if $? == -1;
die( "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"  ) if $? >> 8;
```

or

```perl
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my $output = capturex( "bash", "-i", "-c", "alias" );
```

The latter handles error checking for you, and it avoids running a second shell (avoids running `sh` to run `bash`).

---

1. Aliases aren't usually created in non-interactive shells.

Comment: In non-interactive shells, one has to `shopt -s expand_aliases` to turn on alias expansion.

Comment: @choroba, I don't see how that's remotely relevant to the question or answer. The question doesn't ask how to expand alises in non-interactive shells, and my answer only concerns itself with interactive shells, since we normally only define aliases in those as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I commented on the footnote, but I probably misunderstood the meaning of the verb "created": you probably meant "created by people", I read it as "created by bash".

Comment: @chorobo, Aliases are created by the `alias` directive. I meant that no `alias` directives are  used.

Answer (score 2):

Because `alias` is a shell builtin in interactive shell, so try instead:

```
qx(bash -ci alias)
```